# Non-preemptive authentication is not working with Jetty client library

Tags: authentication, authorization, jetty, preemptive, end-of-life

I am trying to do non-preemptive authentication (get 401-unauthorized with request round trip) with Jetty client. But I'm unable to get request round trip after using below code snippet.

```
AuthenticationStore authStore = client.getAuthenticationStore();
    if(config.getIdentityResource() != null){
        Authentication basicAuthentication = new BasicAuthentication(uri, uri+"" , (getCredentials(config))[0], getCredentials(config)[1]);

        if(config.isUseNonPreemptiveAuth())
        {
            authStore.addAuthentication(basicAuthentication); 
        }
        else if (config.isAuthEnabled() && !config.isUseNonPreemptiveAuth()) 
        {
            authStore.addAuthenticationResult(new BasicAuthentication.BasicResult(uri, (getCredentials(config))[0], getCredentials(config)[1]));
        }
}
```

I'm using jetty-client-9.4.51 jars. Did I miss something in the above code snippet or any Jetty specific property?

I'm expecting to see round trip request based on Jetty documentation as mentioned in [text](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-10/programming-guide/index.html#pg-client-http-authentication:%7E:text=If%20an%20Authentication%20match%20is%20found%2C%20the%20application%20does%20not%20receive%20events%20related%20to%20the%20HTTP%20401%20response.%20These%20events%20are%20handled%20internally%20by%20HttpClient%20which%20produces%20another%20(internal)%20request%20similar%20to%20the%20original%20request%20but%20with%20an%20additional%20Authorization%20header.).

Comment: [Jetty 9.x is now at End of Community Support](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7958) - you should be using Jetty 10, Jetty 11, or even Jetty 12 at this point in time.